# How to distribute data of "type:value" format by categories in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, vba

I am on my way to do linear regression analysis of data parsed from a site.
I was able to get data in the following inconvenient format only:

Data in 1-st column contains data types separated by ':' symbol. For example:

```
Year:Storey:Area:Condition:Type:Name
```

Data in 2-nd column contains information corresponding to data types in 1st column also separated by ':' symbol:

```
2015:3:170:Renovated:TypeB:John
```

---

In my Excel table I have **13000** rows with such data in above mentioned format.
I want to categorize this data by categories specified for the data.
To clarify, I provide picture of original data fromat:
[image]

I try to convert this data to the following format:
[image]

---

I tried to split this data into columns by using delimiters, but the problem is that number of data types varies. 1 row may have 5 categories. Another row may have only 2 categories (data types).

Is it possible to categorize that kind of data in Excel?

Comment: Is the data for each type separated or is it all mixed in?

Comment: Can you tell us the range of storey and area? - e.g. if storey goes from 1 to 50 and area goes from 1 to 1000 you can't tell them apart

Comment: Data for each type is separated by ':' and ordered according to types.

Comment: Sorry, completely misunderstood the question. My last comment should be down-voted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
Sub Andrey()
Dim catArr() As String
Dim resArr() As String
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ows As Worksheet
Dim tws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim startrow As Long

Set ows = Sheets("Sheet9") ' change to where your data is
Set tws = Sheets("Sheet10") ' change to where you want your data

startrow = 3 ' Change to the first row with data

With ows
    lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = startrow To lastrow
        tws.Cells(i, 1) = .Cells(i, 1)
        tws.Range(tws.Cells(i, "B"), tws.Cells(i, "G")).Value = "NULL"
        tws.Range(tws.Cells(i, "B"), tws.Cells(i, "G")).Font.Italic = True
        tws.Range(tws.Cells(i, "B"), tws.Cells(i, "G")).Font.Bold = False
        tws.Range(tws.Cells(i, "A"), tws.Cells(i, "G")).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        catArr = Split(.Cells(i, 2), ":")
        resArr = Split(.Cells(i, 3), ":")
        For j = LBound(catArr) To UBound(catArr)
            tws.Cells(i, WorksheetFunction.Match(catArr(j), tws.Range("A1:G1"), 0)) = resArr(j)
            tws.Cells(i, WorksheetFunction.Match(catArr(j), tws.Range("A1:G1"), 0)).Font.Bold = True
            tws.Cells(i, WorksheetFunction.Match(catArr(j), tws.Range("A1:G1"), 0)).Font.Italic = False
        Next j
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

A couple of caveats.

1) You need to put the data types as titles in the first row of the sheet into which the split data will be placed.

2) I used the rows and columns from your example.  If different then you will need to adjust the cells references.

Edit:  I changed the above to add the "NULL" and format the cells with bold and italics to match better what you want.

Comment: @AndreyRadik Glad I could help.